# Is šns the correct term for "loaf of bread" in Kemetic Ancient Egyptian?

Tags: ancient-egypt, terminology

I am looking for the term "loaf of bread" that was used in ancient Egypt. This is a long timeframe, so I am looking for the term used in the middle period of ancient Egypt. I have found šns used in my research as the term, along with šn, as the term for loaf of bread. I've also seen /t/ used for just the word bread, but also claims that there are 40 words for bread. Any help in clearing up the correct Kemetic words for bread and loaf of bread would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is likely on-topic here too, but you should know that there is also a Linguistics.SE site that might be able to field questions like this.

Comment: Thank you @T.E.D. for the suggestion. I tried that stack, but they closed this question, with the exact same wording as the question above, saying they don't do translations in that stack.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. I'd think that policy would be more useful for "Translate this entire paragraph or page for me please", rather than, "What exactly did this one word mean in ancient Elbonia?", but its their site, their rules.

Comment: @T.E.D. I agree with you. It makes it difficult when the rules are so different from stack to stack.